# TFS client C# API - get all changesets of an Item

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, tfs-sdk

Microsoft TFS client for VS 2010:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.item(v=vs.100).aspx

- I (i.e., my code) have a Changeset.
- I iterate to a particular Change.
- I have an Item in the Change.

Now, I wish to get all Changesets that had Changes for that item.

Could someone advise me the best way to do that?

I could iterate thro all the Changesets of the branch concerned, which would be very inefficient.

Comment: See this. It doesn't get the result you wanted, but it might help: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7ad1d963-a172-47e5-a1eb-bd77c1c58731/programmatically-get-list-of-changesets-for-a-specific-team-project

Comment: `QueryHistory` on the path in question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edward is correct. And he has the credentials to back it up. (See his profile description) 
VersionControlServer.QueryHistory is the method you need to use. There are [several ways](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.queryhistory.aspx) to use it and I'm only describing one below which assumes that the server path of that item is what is important to you...

First, you need the server path of the Item:

```
string serverPath = Item.ServerItem;
```

Next, if you don't already have a VersionControlServer object instantiated, you can get one from your TeamProject like this:

```
VersionControlServer VCServer = (VersionControlServer)this.TeamProject.Store.TeamProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));
```

Use the VersionControlServer QueryHistory(string, boolean) method to get other changesets associated with that server path:

```
VCServer.QueryHistory(serverPath, false);
```

Comment: That will get the items that exist at the specified path currently (and that path's children).  It will not get a single item at previous changesets.

Comment: Thank you. Edward is correct. I have corrected the answer to use Query History instead as he suggested above.