# Get all changesets in a solution via TFS API

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I want to get all changesets of a currently opened team project in Visual Studio 2013 using TFS APIs. I currently have access to the `Workspace` and get the history of single items, but I want to know the whole range of changesets for all files in the solution.

Comment: When you say "changesets for all files in the solution" does that mean all files referenced by the .sln file, or are changes for all files under a folder path sufficient?

Comment: Preferably all referenced in the .sln file, but all files in the folder containing the .sln and the folders below would be a sufficiently good approximation ...

Comment: The folder history will be by far the simplest approach. Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854932/tfs-client-c-sharp-api-get-all-changesets-of-an-item

Comment: I already use `QueryHistory` on files, but I was not aware that I could use it on the folder, too. Do I understand you correct that `RecursionType.Full` on a folder will aggregate all changes in the folder?