# How can I filter TFS changeset history to exclude a certain user?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, changeset

Is it possible to filter changesets in TFS 2012 to exclude the ones from a single user?

The commit history of the solution I currently work on contains quite a lot of noise due to an automated process making a commit each time a build is queued.

I'd like to filter it out to make the commit history more readable.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, try to install [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/index.htm), and check History Sidekick. You can export the records to a .csv file and then filter the user in it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no single query can achieve what you need. You may have to use TFS API.

If you want to get the changesets in a solution via TFS API. The folder history will be the simplest approach. Details please refer this: [TFS client C# API - get all changesets of an Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854932/tfs-client-c-sharp-api-get-all-changesets-of-an-item) You can exclude those changesets from the special user using [Changeset.Committer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.changeset.committer(v=vs.120).aspx) Property which gets the user who committed the changeset.